# Вызов функции при определенном select

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется следующий код: [codepen](https://codepen.io/Broanarchy/pen/GGxxXw)

```
var country = document.getElementById("country");
var sum = document.querySelector("#sum");
window.onload = selectCountry;
country.onchange = selectCountry;
```

[image: И такая вот таблица]
Цифры в таблице это сумма в день. Мне нужно сделать так чтобы при выборе нескольких селектов выводилась нужная мне сумма. Как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
var country = document.getElementById("country");
var sum = document.querySelector("#sum");

window.onload = changeSelect;

country.onchange = changeSelect;
sum.onchange = changeSelect;

function changeSelect(){
  //Ваш код
}
```